# Why did the Evil Queen in 'Snow White' give Snow White the poisonous apple in person?

Tags: disney, snow-white

*The Preamble:*

Something which never made any sense to me is that the objectively beautiful Evil Queen would drink a frightening magical potion which turns her into an old hag, presumably temporarily (but it's barely even implied), with all the risks this entails. What if something about the magic goes wrong and she permanently stays like that? What if the spell kills her in the process, by making her too old/weak?

Why didn't she just pay somebody with less heart and soul than the guy who failed to murder Snow White for her? Why did she have to go through this elaborate process to transform herself and do this all by herself?

The Evil Queen is surely very evil, plotting for Snow White to be buried alive, and clearly torturing and mocking somebody (who is now a skeleton) in her torture dungeon. It's obvious that she must have a bunch of underlings to do her bidding.

---

*The Actual Question:*

**Is there anything from the source materials<sup>*</sup> giving indication of the actual reasons she took this added risk by going to kill Snow White in person?**

* By source materials, I include not just the original Grimms' Fairy Tales from 1812 through to their final revision in 1854, but anything that indicated the earlier local tales may have covered this, although they were probably almost exclusively passed orally back then.

Comment: Something something if you want a job done right.

Comment: The Queen already outsourced one important job (to the huntsman) and it all went completely wrong. As Valorum says, "If you want a job done properly, do it yourself."

Comment: Re-watching the film, it seems fairly obvious why she would choose to go herself.

Comment: The more people who know about the crime you commited the harder it is to keep concealed.

Answer (score 5):

The (Disney) Queen is furious. She's surrounded by incompetents and hucksters. The only way she's going to get this job done is if she does it her **own.damn.self.**

> **Queen:** *The heart of a pig?! The blundering fool!. I'll go **myself** to the dwarfs' cottage in a disguise so complete no one will ever suspect. Now, a formula to transform my beauty into ugliness, change my queenly raiment to a peddler's cloak.*

---

This is expressed very nicely in the 1986 novelisation

> *The Queen grew livid with anger and raising her arm, hurled the
> box at the mirror, shattering it in a thousand pieces. A little laugh
> broke from each splinter of glass and grew and grew until her ears
> were filled with the mocking laughter.*
>
> *In all her life she had never been in such a fury. She kicked and
> screamed with rage. **Through her madness ran but one thought: She
> would destroy the Princess *herself!****
>
> <sub><sup>[The Complete Story of Walt Disney's Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6431023-the-complete-story-of-walt-disney-s-snow-white-and-the-seven-dwarfs)</sup></sub>

Comment: Why would antone novelize a movie already based on a story? Oh well, I guess the same thing happened to _Hairspray_.

Comment: @Spencer - Disney have novelised this film [about twenty times](https://archive.org/search.php?query=disney%27s%20snow%20white&and[]=mediatype%3A%22texts%22) for various ages of readers

Comment: @Valorum sadly some of those readers are the parents of the target audience